# Tornado async request

Tags: python, asynchronous, httprequest, tornado

I have this part of code in Tornado:

```
............
como_url = "".join(['http://', options.como_address, ':', options.como_port, 
                        '/ztc_config?netid=0&opcode_group=0&opcode=0&start=-20s&end=-1s'])

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, como_url)

ret = {}
if response.error:
    ret['error'] = 'Error while retrieving the response'
    self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(ret))
    self.finish()
else:
.........
```

I send a command to a sensor and after I do an http request to a db to retrieve the response from sensor.
And after I take the response and do some actions.

Now, I have to send the http request two times to retrieve the response. The first time I send a command to the sensor, is something like the request is too fast to receive the response.

After I resend the command, the response is found right and all is fine.

Why? How can I set I don't know a timeout to the request... or how can I resend in Tornado the request two times?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I wrote like this:

```
como_url = "".join(['http://', options.como_address, ':', options.como_port, 
                        '/ztc_config?netid=0&opcode_group=0&opcode=0&start=-20s&end=-1s'])

    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    #response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, como_url)
    request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url=como_url, connect_timeout=5.0, request_timeout=2.0)
    response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, request)
    print response
```

and I obtain:

```
HTTPResponse(code=200,request_time=0.30609703063964844,buffer=<io.BytesIO object at 0x276a1d0>,_body=None,time_info={},request=<tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest object at 0x2764310>,effective_url='http://131.114.52.207:44444/ztc_config?netid=0&opcode_group=0&opcode=0&start=-20s&end=-1s',headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},error=None)
```

Why request_time=0????

Comment: can you post the error you get when you send the response the first time? `is something like the request is too fast to receive` is vague

Comment: I didn't receive any error... if I look the screen of Tornado, I see the command is sent and anything else... the second time the command is sent and after I see the response... I think it's a problem of CoMo DB. I don't know if it's possible to set a request with parameter 'end' = +10s (seconds)... something like this.

Comment: Is the http_client.fetch timing out the first time, or do you want to just delay the call to fetch?  If it's the later then ioloop.add_timeout is going to be useful.

Comment: Can I add the timeout here response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, como_url) ? How can I do?

Comment: See my edit. I set the timeouts but it doesn't still work.

Comment: request time is in seconds. So that translates to 306 milliseconds.

Comment: You can run `response = yield http_client.fetch(request)`, without the need to wrap in a `gen.Task`.